# как сделать прозрачные стены когда за ней игрок, как в Diablo? UNITY

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создаю игру в Unity по типу Diablo и мне необходимо понять каким образом можно сделать стены или обьекты за которыми находится игрок прозрачными чтобы не мешали обзору, показано на этом видео:

( на 20 секунде, обратите внимание на колонну которая исчезает) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRBe-u5mZho

**РЕШЕНО:** Благодаря ответу ниже, сторонним сайтам, и статьям мне удалось добиться близкого результата, пустив Raycast, я изменял на обьекте материал на прозрачный, и использовал шейдеры смог добиться результата которого хотел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Бросать из камеры рейкаст в позицию персонажа. Если в массиве результатов есть кто-то кроме персонажа - делать их прозрачными и куда-нибудь записывать. В следующем кадре менять прозрачность обратно тем, которых нет в новом массиве столкновений и включать тем, которых нет в сохранённом списке.

Comment: а я бы шейдер написал =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я в них не силён) потому сказал, что в голову пришло. С помощью шейдера, наверное, оптимальнее - можете оставить дополнительный ответ, думаю, он явно не будет лишним :)